# Is there an Interactive mode (like dev tools Console) for Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, interactive

If i'm doing some javascript on a web page it's really useful to be able to step through it a line at a time manually, in the console, to check that everything's doing what i think it's doing.

Is there an equivalent interactive mode in Apps Script?  I know that I can go into debug mode, but I can't seem to find a mode where I can just type my own commands in and see what I get back, like I can in Console.  I'm using Apps Script to build new Google Presentation docs by combining data from a spreadsheet and a template Presentation doc.  It would be great, especially because i'm new to Apps Script, to just be able to experiment a line at a time.

Comment: The editor has a debugger

Answer (score 2):

For now there's only debug mode, and you can just set a function aside to test small snippets if that's what you're looking for. This has been requested a while ago in Google's [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76213503), but it hasn't received much attention so far. You may want to consider [posting a better feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113).

Also, this is borderline unrelated since it's not exactly for testing or debugging, but while we're on the subject of command lines you could take a look at [Clasp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp). This is a command-line tool that allows you to locally work with Apps Script projects and even remotely run functions, so you could combine it with your preferred IDE to make your life easier.